# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied openshift

Tags: java, sockets, openshift

I'm trying to make several socket connection in an app. deployed on oTomcat OpenShift and I get this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

My Account is free it's possible that with a payment Account openshift let me make binding to several port (open several sockect).

Comment: You need super-user permission to bind to a port under 1024.

Answer (score 1):

For plain WebSockets ws:// you can port 8000 and for secured connections wss:// port 8443. This blog goes into more detail https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets and should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I try run mine on port 8000, but still get the permission denied error. Any Ideas?  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266277/openshift-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied?noredirect=1#comment65870562_39266277