# Openshift java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: java, sockets, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am using Java8 and have a **Chat Server** that works perfectly on my *localhost*, but when I deploy it to an OpenShift server, I get the following error:

> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
>
> ```
> 2016-09-05 10:36:11,300 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-125) Starting Chat server on localhost:8000 ...
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,194 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125) Exception in thread "Thread-125" java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,194 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,195 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,195 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,195 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,195 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,196 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,196 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:476)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,196 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadHandler.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1000)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,196 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:463)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,197 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.bind(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:448)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,197 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:842)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,197 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:195)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,197 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:338)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,198 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,198 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,198 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
> 2016-09-05 10:36:13,198 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-125)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

I have looked at the OpenShift web sockets guide [here](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/), which says port 8000 should be used. But I still get the error.

On Openshift I am running my **chat server** on a *WildFly Application Server 10* cartridge.

Any advise appreciated.

Here is my code:

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
    try {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                com.jobs.spring.chat.Server chatServer = new com.jobs.spring.chat.Server();
                chatServer.startServer();
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Server.java**

```
import java.net.Socket;

import com.corundumstudio.socketio.AckRequest;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOClient;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.ConnectListener;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.DataListener;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.DisconnectListener;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/
 * @author Richard
 *
 */
public class Server {

    //private static final String SERVER = "localhost";
    private static final String SERVER = "jbosswildfly-easyjobs.rhcloud.com";
    private static final Integer PORT = 8000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startServer();
    }

    public static void startServer() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname(SERVER);
        config.setPort(PORT);
        final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);

        server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
                System.out.println("onConnected");
                client.sendEvent("chat_message:message", new Message("Welcome to the chat!"));
            }
        });

        server.addDisconnectListener(new DisconnectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDisconnect(SocketIOClient client) {
                System.out.println("onDisconnected");
            }
        });

        server.addEventListener("chat_message:send", String.class, new DataListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, String data, AckRequest ackSender) throws Exception {
                Message message = null;
                try {
                    message = new ObjectMapper().readValue(data.toString(), Message.class);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                message.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("chat_message:message", message);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Starting Chat server on " + SERVER + ":" + PORT+" ...");
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Chat server started");
        System.out.println("Chat server Environment Info: " + System.getenv());
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER, PORT);
            printSocketInformation(socket);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prints debug output (to stdout) for the given Java Socket.
     */
    public static void printSocketInformation(Socket socket) {
        try {
            System.out.format("Port:                 %s\n", socket.getPort());
            System.out.format("Canonical Host Name:  %s\n", socket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName());
            System.out.format("Host Address:         %s\n\n", socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            System.out.format("Local Address:        %s\n", socket.getLocalAddress());
            System.out.format("Local Port:           %s\n", socket.getLocalPort());
            System.out.format("Local Socket Address: %s\n\n", socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
            System.out.format("Receive Buffer Size:  %s\n", socket.getReceiveBufferSize());
            System.out.format("Send Buffer Size:     %s\n\n", socket.getSendBufferSize());
            System.out.format("Keep-Alive:           %s\n", socket.getKeepAlive());
            System.out.format("SO Timeout:           %s\n", socket.getSoTimeout());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In [this link](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html) OpenShift talk about port binding and proxies. I don't really understand all of it. It looks like I should use port 8000 (which I am), but I am not clear what hostname I should use. I am using my application url name (jbosswildfly-easyjobs.rhcloud.com). Is that correct?

If I change the address to, `http://jbosswildfly-easyjobs.rhcloud.com` (i.e. prefix `http://`) I get the following error:

> java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address

[image]

Comment: You get this exception when doing what?

Comment: It's when I start up the server.

Comment: You get this exception doing what when starting up the server? Which line of code? Where is the stack trace? What is the actual question?

Comment: When `WebAppInitializer.java` in the example above starts the thread calling the `startServer()` method on `Server.java`.

Comment: I will ask you for the third time. When doing **what?** Exactly? **Post the stack trace.**

Comment: Apologies......I'll add the stack trace above

Comment: Have you checked whether your `truststore` contains your server's certificate if it doesn't have a proper certificate?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find out solution. I have got some solutions. All are suggesting to add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the VM options.

[Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/mail-server-connection-failed-with-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-exception-364609886.html) also got the root cause and solution given below:

> **Cause**
>
> 1. This is one of the known issues with Java 7, as per [this post](https://www.java.net//node/703177).
> 2. This can also be caused by any anti-virus or firewall software
>    installed on the server.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> 1. Use the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` JVM system property to help
>    enable support for IPv4 on Java 7.
> 2. Check that anti-virus and firewall software on the server is not
>    blocking Stash's ability to connect to the mail server.

**This solution is for Java 7, but you are using Java 8.** So I lookup your stacktrace. There is a line

```
 at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
```

Which is telling that you are using **netty**.

But netty has some requirement on version basis. There is also some limitations.

> JDK 5 (Netty 3.x) or 6 (Netty 4.x) is enough. Some components such as
> HTTP/2 might have more requirements

### Requirements for Netty 4.x([link](http://netty.io/wiki/requirements-for-4.x.html))

> **Java does not currently support ALPN or NPN (there [is a tracking issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051498) so go upvote it!). For lack of support in the JDK we need to
> use the Jetty-ALPN (or Jetty-NPN if on Java < 8) bootclasspath
> extension for OpenJDK.** To do this, add a Xbootclasspath JVM option
> referencing the path to the Jetty alpn-boot jar.
>
> ```
> java -Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/jetty/alpn/extension.jar ...
> ```
>
> Note that you must use the [release of the Jetty-ALPN jar](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions) specific
> to the version of Java you are using.
>
> ### JDK Ciphers
>
> **Java 7 does not support [the cipher suites recommended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-9.2.2) by the HTTP2 RFC**. To address this we suggest servers use Java 8 where
> possible or use an alternative JCE implementation such as [Bouncy
> Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html). If this is not practical it is possible to use other
> ciphers but you need to ensure that the services you intend to call
> also support these ciphers forbidden by the HTTP/2 RFC and have
> evaluated the security risks of doing so.
>
> ### Enabling ALPN or NPN
>
> The [SslContextBuilder](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder.java#L279) has a setter for an [ApplicationProtocolConfig](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/ApplicationProtocolConfig.java) which is used to configure ALPN or NPN.
> See the [HTTP/2 examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld) for ALPN and [SPDY examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/spdy) for NPN
> usage.

For details description, you can go through [this link](http://netty.io/wiki/requirements-for-4.x.html).

### Suggestions:

**So check your netty version and take decision according above issues. Or use JDK 7 if possible.**

Comment: Thank you. I will go through your answer tomorrow when I have some time.

Answer (score 2):

The linked blog post says that you can connect to websockets on OpenShift using ports 8000 and 8443. However, the server itself needs to be bound only to port **8080** and then you can connect externally to the ws ports above. [This diagram](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html) that you have already found explains the configuration.

WildFly is using 8080 already, so you may want to use the [DIY cartridge](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/diy.html) to deploy your app (don't forget to disable the default ruby server in the start action hook that is running on 8080) or be inspired [here](https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-websocket-web-applications-with-jboss-wildfly/).